# Please, can anybody help in writing a server-client raw socket program in c/c++

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, raw-sockets

I am new to raw socket. I want write a server and a client application that use raw sockets to send and receive raw data in one or more files.  Each file may contain one or more data segments of 50 bytes each with a designated delimiters (i.e., space, carriage return, and etc.)  The job of my server is to read from the file and send each segment at a time.  Each packet should only contain the data without any traditional header information such as the Ethernet header like the MAC addresses (the packet may contain some form of data in front of the packet to indicate the length and/or the start of the packet and the delimiter to indicate the end of the packet).  The client application should simply listen to the 
port, parse the data and write the raw data into a file.

Please, guide me. I have found many raw socket programs but, none were clear. If anybody could give me a solid start then that would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure what you describe is even possible. To listen to a port requires TCP protocol. If you send data without an Ethernet header, how will a router know where to route packets? Transferring files between a client and a server does not require raw sockets. Just use a stream socket for this.

Comment: Sir, you are not getting my point. I want to use 4 to 5 nodes to do this with a single router in between. But, my 1st aim is to have a simple server and client running. I am just putting the mac address in the header and sending the packet. So, that the receiver knows from where I came.....

Comment: Well.. I'm still not getting it. Maybe it's the bit where it says "each packet should only contain the data without any traditional header information such as Ethernet header" that has me confused. Also, if you're looking at Windows, then TCP over raw sockets will not work. I'm still unsure why you want to use raw sockets at all for this. Client / server stuff like this is classic stream sockets. Maybe you could clarify your answer more so I can see what you're really attempting to do?

Comment: Why are you fixated on using raw sockets? There's unlikely to be any advantage to using them, and many major drawbacks. Just use TCP or UDP over IP, unless you have some incredibly specific need to avoid them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see here : http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw, but what you say is really possible.
In fact, imagine that, in your data, you have data that match a protocol which can be routed, the packet will be routed. Indeed, if you see documentation, Raw socket handle header and payload. You MUST have a header (in your case, it must begin with 0 to say personnal header, and after no header, juste payload). And, maybe it can be work with a very basic router/switch, but nowaday, it's sound difficult because router look data and may imagine this is corrupted data.